# Use Aura Component Attribute as Javascript Variable Name

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

Was wondering if it is possible to use a string component attribute to target defined javascript variables.

This is what i am looking to do

```
var owner = initial[i].Policy_Owner__c ? initial[i].Policy_Owner__r.Name : "Awaiting Owner"

var policy = initial[i].Insurance_Carrier__c initial[i].Insurance_Carrier__r.Name : "Carrier Not Listed"

saver.push(component.get('v.sortedby'));
```

sortedby is a string attribute. There is definitely a workaround for this particular situation but i am more wondering on the general concept of how to use component attributes to dynamically target javascript variables

Answer (score 2):

You'd use an Object if you wanted to select a specific element, like this:

```
var values = {
  owner: initial[i].Policy_Owner__r.Name || 'Awaiting Owner',
  policy: initial[i].Insurance_Carrier__r.Name || 'Carrier Not Listed'
}, sortedBy = component.get('v.sortedBy');
saver.push(values[sortedBy]);
```

This method of dynamically choosing a value falls under [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

---

In "normal" JavaScript, we could also just "eval", but this is specifically disallowed in Aura in order to prevent developers bypassing Locker Service security features.